# Help understanding how to build a web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp-classic

I have a client who has an ASP shopping cart (classic asp) and a Windows based point of sale system both using their own SQL Server databases.

The maker of the Windows point of sale system has a utility that will export the inventory as an XML file and will also retrieve any sales from the shopping cart if it is in their special XML format.

I asked them "where do I make the XML request for the inventory" and they told me it had to be done as a web service.  I assumed that their software would either have a place for me to do a POST or GET request for the XML via HTTP or that it would generate it as a file on the hard drive.  I have never built a web service, although I have been a developer for more than 15 years, so forgive me for my newbie-ness to this :)

Can anyone get me started with some links or any suggestions on how I can understand this better?

If I understood how I would make a request and allow requests for XML files with a web service, I'm sure I could build it.

Comment: Ask them for an example of calling the web service. Even if it's not a Classic ASP example, either you'll understand it, or you can post the info here, and _we'll_ understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This [site](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t76035-calling-a-net-web-service-from-classic-asp.html) seems to have a decent example.